# Windows 10 "Refresh": is this a real thing or a hack/virus?

Tags: windows

Folks,

A friend who is a seasoned computer user, but not a techy at all, had a message come up on her computer which was doing the usual Winrot thing and slowing down with each passing month. It said - and I'm paraphrasing here because I got this story from her -

> Your machine is running slow, would you like to "refresh" your
>   computer? This will get rid of unused apps and data and speed the
>   computer up, it will take about twenty minutes.

So she thought why not and went for it. However, it took all night to complete the operation and has uninstalled Thunderbird, MS Office, some translation tools (she's a translator) and loads of other apps and also seems to have got rid of all her old emails.

So the big question is: Is this Windows "refresh" thing a genuine operation or is she victim to a virus/trojan attack?

I or she found something that said a Windows refresh will uninstall all programs not installed from the Windows App store. I assume this Windows apps store is like a Linux repository/Apple's iTunes?  She also does have a list of items uninstalled.

I still think there's a chance her old emails are on the computer because I transferred them from an old one to this and I likely put the old email files in a directory that I had Thunderbird point to, however, she has lost a load of other data in terms of preferences for translation tools etc.

I assume that if she has been hacked she's best off wiping the machine? Obv. she doesn't have a restore point saved anywhere.

Comment: The “Refresh” feature is certainly an official Windows thing. Never heard of a notification suggesting it though. Maybe your question should be about how to get the data back.

Comment: Winrot doesn’t actually exist.  Refresh is indeed a legitimate feature.  Your friends files are in Windows.old.  They won’t be there more than 15 days before they are wiped.

Comment: Refresh does not exist on Windows 10, just Reset, with Reset offering a few different options.  For all intents and purposes, a Reset is a clean install, minus wiping `%UserProfile%`.  If on version 18** or newer, Reset now performs a reset via the `C:\Windows\WinSxS` directory, reinstalling all drivers that were present as of the last major update (Mar & Sep), however it removes all software not installed via the Windows Store.  Just an FYI, it's quicker to create a WIM of `%UserProfile%`, clean install Windows, and install the Chipset drivers, than it is to do a Reset.

Comment: Thanks for the Windows.old tip, that could be v. useful. :) We'll agree to disagree on the Winrot front! ;)

Comment: @JW0914 I have seen so many things on line with some people saying refresh does exist and others saying it doesn't I don't know what to think any more! Your reset thing really does sound like that's what she's done, not refresh.

Comment: “If on version 18** or newer” - What?  Any event, I suspect “Fresh Start” was actually the feature used, which downloads and reinstalls Windows.  Likewise, Reset, uses the image that already exists on the machine to reinstall Windows.  **Refresh** only exists on Windows 8, Reset and Refresh, was merged into a single feature with Windows 10.

Comment: @DiBosco Refresh was an option in Windows 8 and was removed in Windows 10 (see Settings > Update & Security > Recovery).  If receiving conflicting information, [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com) should be consulted =]

Comment: @Ramhound That is no longer how Reset works in Windows 10.  Reset now utilizes the `WinSxS` directory since Windows version 1803 or 1809

Comment: @JW0914 - I am aware of how Reset on Windows 10.  I have no idea what you meant by “version 18” though.  You don’t need to tell me how Reset works on Windows 10.  I am not trying to take the quoted text to literally since I don’t believe it’s the exact message that was received (and I suspect Fresh Start was the feature suggested not Refresh/Reset)

Comment: @Ramhound I think you may have misread my comment - In Win10 ver 1803 or 1809 _(it might have even been in ver 1703 or 1709)_, Microsoft changed the way in which Resets are done. Prior to this change, an `install.wim` would have been utilized, but as of ver 1803 or 1809 _(or 1703 / 1709)_, Reset now utilizes the WinSxS directory to reinstall Windows. Microsoft made this change as it now allows for all drivers installed as of the last bi-annual update (Mar & Sep) to be included in the re-install since a backup of these drivers are now stored in the WinSxS directory (`C:\Windows\WinSxS`)

Comment: @JW0914 - Your comments refers to "version 18" of something.  I literally asked for clarification.  When you use "version 18", if you are actually referring to version 1803 and 1809, that would explain my confusion.  As I said I am aware of the changes how Reset works.

Comment: @Ramhound I said version 18**, not 18.  It could also be written 18xx

Comment: @JW0914 - I wouldn't have known you mean 1803 and 1809 by saying 18** unless you told me thats what it meant.  ** are also used to bold text in a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Great point, I didn't think about it like that

Answer (score -4):

I have no idea which software has displayed that idiotic message,
which I would even call criminal.

If it has truly refreshed your computer with the original version of Windows,
then there are two options: This was done with preserving user data or not.
In both cases, all apps are lost.

I suggest to first check if some of the user's data is still on the disk.
If it is, then recovery might be possible as follows:

- Run *Settings*
- Go into *Update & security*
- Click *Recovery*
- Under *Go back to an earlier build*, click the button *Get Started*
- Wait as long as required to return Windows to its previous version.

If you manage to return the previous Windows version, I would suggest some
deep antivirus scans by well-known products. The "helpful" product that
caused the problem should be uninstalled and eradicated.

If the *Get Started* button is disabled, then no recovery is possible.
If the user data is still on the disk, then you only need to install
the missing apps.
Otherwise, I suggest in this case to shutdown the computer and use some data-recovery
products from a boot disk, or take the hard disk out and use such a product
in another computer. Remember to always recover data to an external disk,
never to the disk being recovered.

The following article lists some data recovery software with reviews:
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Comment: Thanks, Harry. To confirm, this isn't my computer, I'm just trying to help a non-techy person out. She thinks her data is gone, which I must say seems a weird thing for a refresh, which is why I am worried it might be a virus and leeching who knows what off her computer. It is possible she thought it was a refresh and it was actually a reset which might explain the loss of so much, however, that seems like an strange thing to for an official  "feature", even allowing for MS factor.

Comment: I thought (and I am no Windows expert) that a restore was something you have to reset and go into the alternative boot menu to achieve.

Comment: The Settings app can do that in Windows 10 (which I assume is her version). If "Go back to an earlier build" is available, then this seems legitimate.

Comment: You can initiate a restore point from within Windows but it requires a reboot.  You can also initiate the process to revert to a previous build of Windows from within Windows (which actually cannot be done outside of Windows)

Comment: @harrymc It's cool, we'll give it a go and see whether it helps. No harm in trying :)

Comment: @harrymc Are you 100% _Go back to an earlier build_ allows reversal of a Reset?  The way that function works is via the two hidden folders and the `Windows.old` directory that exists in the root of the C: partition after a bi-annual update (Mar & Sep), but I wasn't aware that a Reset creates the same for this functionality.  _(FYI: I've never done a Reset because, at such a point, a clean install is faster and more efficient)_

Comment: @JW0914: As I said above, I'm not sure of anything since I don't know what really happened and all info here is second hand. I tried to cover all cases in my answer, including when Go back is impossible.

Comment: @JW0914 Isn't a clean install on Windows a nightmare? My past experience is that Linux is a doddle and Windows really difficult, because you have to go scouring the web for drivers. Have things improved in the last fifteen years or so sinice I dumped Windows? A little OT now, I know...

Comment: There are utilities for that. See [Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Comment: @DiBosco - A clean install of Windows 10 could not be any easier.  You install Windows 10, Windows Update installs all required drivers, any drivers that are still required can be manually installed (no difference to any other version of Windows).

Comment: @JW0914 - While Reset does indeed create a Windows.old directory just like installing a feature upgrade creates one, you cannot actually revert your Windows installation, if you use Reset (unlike installing a feature upgrade or performing an in-place repair (i.e. use an iso).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97470/discussion-between-ramhound-and-harrymc).